# Dialog с стрелкой

Tags: android, dialogfragment

Простите за сомнительный заголовок, товарищи, но не знаю как правильно это описать.
В общем нужно сделать кастомный диалог с такой вот стрелочкой (только вверх)
[image: диалог]
Подскажите как добавить такую стрелочку в мой диалог (в идеале сразу вверх)?
Мой фрагмент:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:background="@drawable/my_background">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView_dialog_event"
        style="@style/PrimaryTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/text_dialog"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: это называется маркер, он ставится на картах. что вы хотите? поставить такой же маркер куда-то а в диалоге должна быть карта.

Comment: у меня тоже есть карта но маркер другой, но не в этом суть,
видите над маркером диалог?
вот у меня кастомный диалог вместо того что вы видите
и мне нужно что б у моего диалога была такая же стрелочка как у этого
(та что идет от прямоугольника к маркеру)

Comment: ну так если он у вас кастомный есть смысл показать, что вы сделали. а в целом если вы уже сделали кастомный, значит рисовали на канве, так дорисуйте стрелочку, в чем проблема? Покажите как вы это делаете, на словах тяжело, сейчас выяснится что мы про разное говорим. Да и на картах это если не ошибаюсь называется что-то типо InfoWindow параметр маркера

Comment: вы хотите это на Google Map делать, или вы просто хотите сделать такую VIew у себя где-то там в Activity. Просто это совершенно разные вещи. Уточните вопрос, ваши комменты ешё больше вводят в заблуждение

Comment: Это на Google Map